# Cannot run Taurus.yml file from Concourse CI

Tags: jmeter, concourse, blazemeter, taurus

Trying to run Taurus.yml file from Concourse CI and getting "Network Error: Request to https://a.blazemeter.com/api/v4/web/version failed" Error.

Here are my Concourse CI pipeline code and Taurus.yml file.
https://github.com/skreddy6673/jmeter-on-concourse The same Taurus.yml file worked when ran locally using the same docker image following https://qautomation.blog/2019/09/23/running-jmeter-scripts-by-taurus-docker-image/

Any example code or pointers are much really helpful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your pipeline; it seems like your Concourse worker can't reach out to the internet. How are you running Concourse? If it's deployed on a public cloud, check your egress rules from your workers.